# change variable value inside app from outside

Tags: android

I want to declare a key inside my code and publish app with this key, then when app is published I want to be able change that key.
But my aim is to have one app and customize it for different users.
Do you have any offer? 
May you explain a scenario?

Note : better to say that I want to separate each user's version by a unique key; 
1- I can do this : I can change the variable value, publish app and send for user. But I wand to change key value in a published app, not from source code and re-publish.
2- using external file,  shared-preference, and other ways, user will loose his version when uninstall app, and I want to avoid it.

Comment: You need server communication for this

Comment: By "Key" u mean Keystore or Preference Key?

Comment: you can get your application's key from the server and store in application's preference or in database or in file and can use it later.

Comment: "key" I mean internal variable value, defined in my app.

Comment: I have seen a solution that used inside project and after publish, would let developer to change some app parameters of app, How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just declare key in String.xml,

if you want to changes key run time, you have to go with sharedpreference in android, this store data in xml format.

more help visit this link, [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) : no saving to device, change it inside a packed app!

also this will help you [Storage option in android](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) : no storage, it is change value in a compiled app!

Comment: Thanks, but all these ways cause data loose when uninstall. I look for a way to change key(value) of a published app, manually or by a (for example) a windows app (automated way).